# iOS - Changing control points of Quad Curve?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I have drawn a quad curve with the following code, I also drew 3 ellipses, one for left corner, one for right corner and one for control point.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGMutablePathRef curve = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(curve, nil, 5, 40);
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(curve, nil, 30, 20, 55, 40);

CGContextAddPath(context, curve);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGSize sz = self.frame.size;
CGPoint pt = CGPointMake(sz.width/2.0, sz.height/2.0);
CGFloat r = 5;

middleRect_ = CGRectMake(pt.x - r, pt.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);

CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, middleRect_);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, middleRect_);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

//left side

sz = self.frame.size;
pt = CGPointMake(sz.width/2.0, sz.height/2.0);
r = 5;

leftRect_ = CGRectMake(pt.x - 27, pt.y + 3, r * 2, r * 2);

CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, leftRect_);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, leftRect_);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

//right side
sz = self.frame.size;
pt = CGPointMake(sz.width/2.0, sz.height/2.0);
r = 5;
rightRect_ = CGRectMake(pt.x + 20, pt.y + 3, r * 2, r * 2);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rightRect_);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rightRect_);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

// Cleanup Code
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}
```

as you can can see I am using 3 CGRects to store the positions. Now I want that whenenver I touch and drag an ellipse, it changes the curve. for example if touch the middle ellipse, it changes the control point, if I touch the leftRect, it changes left position, if I touch rightRect, it changes the right position. How to do that? I dont have the reference of these ellipses and curve, how can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need track the touch events to know when the user starts dragging an ellipse. Use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for that. You also need variables to keep track of the locations of the ellipses. Whenever user drags an ellipse, redraw everything by calling `[self setNeedsDisplay]`.

Sorry for the brief answer, but it's a long way from drawing a quad curve to allowing users to control it. The algorithm is pretty straight forward though.

Comment: redraw means removing everything and then redrawing again?

Comment: You don't really have to remove. Just add a `CGContextFillRect` at the beginning of `drawRect`.

Comment: I added it and it added a blackish background

Comment: You need to set the color with `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` before calling `CGContextFillRect`